# Is unit speech on Age Of Empires made up?

Tags: age-of-empires

The unit speech in Age of Empires seems like a made-up one, a kind of ["Simlish"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SpeakingSimlish) (warning TV Tropes). Is it completely made up, or was it somewhat based on a language? Some of the responses sound vaguely Latin, with the -us suffixes.

Comment: This would be the first game only, if that.  The second one uses faction-specific audio, for obvious reasons mapped to the origin countries' language...

Comment: Is that question title appropriate? Doesn't it have to be a "clear"  an "real" question? (this sounds serious, but rules are rules right?) :) [I btw laughed reading the question title :D]

Comment: I remember one of my friends saying that at least some of it was based on german. uncomfirmed.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately I cannot find any sources for the original Age of Empires, but every game in the series from Age of Empires II onwards (AoE III, AoM, etc.) have in-game dialogue based on the language of the civilization (with exception of the Atlanteans in Age of Mythology, who speak a made up language).

You can find the unit speeches and translation on the Age of Empires wiki - for example, here's the one for [Britons in Age of Empires II](http://ageofempires.wikia.com/wiki/Britons#In-game_dialogue_language).

Answer (score 2):

Many of the words in AOEI are more derived from Latin (i.e. erectus) than Dutch or Germanic languages.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be mostly Germanic/ Dutch derivatives. I noticed this because it's similar to my language Afrikaans, which itself is a Germanic Dutch derivative.  I can almost translate most of the words.

Comment: It would be great to know some examples of the translations you mention